# VB.Net How to run the application in a specific folder?

Tags: java, asp.net, vb.net, batch-file

So a little bit of my code is to run an application (a batch file in an external folder that the user can select.) The problem is that when I use

`Path.GetDirectoryName(O.FileName) + "\BasicStart.bat"`

however when I try to do the above it fails to open to java application due to the class folders trying to be referenced from where the vb.net application is launched

The code in the .bat is

```
@echo off
@title JavaApplet12
set CLASSPATH=.;dist\*
java -client -Dnet.sf.odinms.wzpath=wz server.Start
pause
```

And I know I can hard set the classpath and wzpath but users of my application will not want to do this.

How can I launch it in vb.net so that the application is launched from that location and can read the files from that folder location.

Comment: Can you post the code that you use to run this bat file?

Comment: The user selects the application from a file dialouge

Process.Start(Path.GetDirectoryName(O.FileName))

Answer (score 1):

This should be resolvable by setting the working directory of the process before you start it:

```
Dim processStartInfo = New ProcessStartInfo()
processStartInfo.WorkingDirectory = Path.GetDirectoryName(O.FileName)
processStartInfo.FileName = "BasicStart.bat"
Process.Start(processStartInfo)
```

Comment: Is there anyway that you could have this in vb.net?

Comment: @Brandon, ouch, sorry, I forgot this is vb.net question